# Space Invaders: JFrame Collision Detection and Reversing Direction

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am a Java beginner, trying to design space invaders game. I have 5 rows of 6 aliens that move across the screen in sync. When they hit the edge they are supposed to move down a small bit and then reverse direction. I have been trying for hours to no avail, any help would be hugely appreciated.
BONUS: if anyone can tell me why the last alien in the bottomright corner isn't being created that would be great.
main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.*;
public class InvadersApplication extends JFrame implements
Runnable, KeyListener {
//member data
private static String workingDirectory;
private static boolean isGraphicsInitialised=false;
public static final Dimension WindowSize = new Dimension(800,600);
private static final int NUMALIENS = 30;
private double alienx, alieny;
private Sprite2D[] GeneralArray = new Sprite2D[NUMALIENS+3];
private SpaceShip PlayerShip;
private BufferStrategy strategy;


//constructor
public InvadersApplication (){

    //display the window, centred on the screen
    Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = screensize.width/2-WindowSize.width/2;
    int y = screensize.height/2-WindowSize.height/2;
    setBounds (x, y, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);
    setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Space Invaders!");
    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = getBufferStrategy();




    //load image from disk
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C://Users/MRDJR97/JAVAIMAGES/alien.png");
    Image alienImage = icon.getImage();

    //create and initialise some aliens, passing them each into the image we have     loaded
        int i=1;
        alienx=20; alieny=30;
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            alienx=20;
            for(int k=0; k<5; k++){
                GeneralArray[i] = new Alien(alienImage);
                GeneralArray[i].setPosition(alienx, alieny);
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
                alienx+=67;
            }
            alieny+=50;
        }




    //create and initialise the player's spaceship
    icon = new ImageIcon("C://Users/MRDJR97/JAVAIMAGES/playership.png");
    Image shipImage = icon.getImage();
    PlayerShip = new SpaceShip(shipImage);
    PlayerShip.setPosition(200, 530);
    GeneralArray[0] = PlayerShip;

    //create and start animation thread
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();

    //send keyboard events arriving into this JFrame back to its own event handlers
    addKeyListener(this);
    isGraphicsInitialised=true; // it is now safe to paint the images

}

//thread's entry point
public void run(){
    while(1==1) {
        //1:sleep for 1/50 of a second
        try{Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        //2:animate game objects
        for(int i=0; i<NUMALIENS; i++){
            GeneralArray[i].move();

        PlayerShip.move();

        this.repaint(); //3: force an application repaint 
        }}
    }

//Three Keyboard Event-handler functions
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {PlayerShip.setXSpeed(-4);}
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {PlayerShip.setXSpeed(4);}
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT||e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        PlayerShip.setXSpeed(0);}
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    //applications paint method
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        if (isGraphicsInitialised){
            g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            //don't try to draw unitialised objects
            //clear canvas w big black rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);
            //redraw all game objects
            for(int i =0; i<NUMALIENS; i++){
                GeneralArray[i].paint(g);
            PlayerShip.paint(g);
            }
            g.dispose();
            strategy.show();
            }
        }
    //application entry point
        public static void main(String [] args){
            workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            InvadersApplication w = new InvadersApplication();      
    }
}
```

Alien Class (which extends to a superclass[Sprite2D]):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Alien extends Sprite2D{

public Alien(Image i) {
    super(i);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
public void move(){
    x+= 5;

 }
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few basic bad choices in the code. I would advise going over the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). I see all sorts of threading and painting problems that are beyond the scope of a single question. Also, `Sprite2D` isn't a JavaSE class.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach. See also the _Space Invaders_ tutorial cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12600669/230513).