# Update jtable with changes from model every 1 second

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer, jtable

I have a JTable with an AbstractTableModel containing data in a ArrayList. The list is only a few elements, but the properties of the objects changes rapidly (maybe 100 times per second)

I guess it will give bad performance to fire changes all the time.

Is it okay to use a timer to trigger JTable update every 1 second?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {                
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myModel.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(myModel));
        }
    });
timer.start();
```

Comment: `TableChanged` is not a good idea, as it affects the current selection and column information, including renderers and editors.  You should also not be calling the event triggers (`fireXxx`) from outside the models context, as it's not your responsibility.  Instead, create a custom table with one or more update methods that trigger `tableRowsUpdated` instead for example.

Comment: Another solution might be to allow the model to actually do it's job and instead of reading the data directly from the changing `ArrayList`, which might cause race conditions between the `ArrayList` and the UI, use a `DefaultTableModel` and simply call `setValueAt` (or if empty, `addRow`), making sure you synchronise the updates between what ever is updating the `ArrayList` and the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: It sounds cumbersome. In .net WPF and MVVM I could make a model with PropertyChanged events that would make the GUI update whenever another thread changes the model. This is fully thread safe.

Comment: Swing is not thread safe

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). You can collect data in your implementation of `doInBackground()`, `publish()` interim results, and `process()` changes to the `TableModel` on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) at a [sustainable rate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838349/230513). A complete example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384208/230513).