# Delayed graph display when receiving data from BufferedReader

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a very serious problem with JFreeChart . We wrote a program by C on the Tinker Board that takes the data from the ADXL355 sensor and displays it in shell.
Then, with a program we wrote in Java, we received the data using a buffered reader and displayed it in graphs. There is no problem when we print the received data only in the output; but when we send the data to the graph for display, it is displayed with a delay of 30 seconds and this delay increases over time.

We use `JFrame` form; here is Java side:

```
package client_time;

import com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.omg.CORBA.TIMEOUT;


public class cha_time extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    public  TimeSeries TSx , TSy , TSz ;
    public  TimeSeriesCollection DataSetx , DataSety , DataSetz  ; 
    public  int x = 0 ;
    public  double Give_doubleX , Give_doubleY , Give_doubleZ ;
    public String Give_stringX , Give_stringY , Give_stringZ;
    public boolean Statuse = true ;
    public String line;
    public BufferedReader BR;
    public Process process;
    public InputStreamReader isr;
    public int i = 0 ;
    public  cha_time() {
        initComponents();
        line = "";
        Give_doubleX = 0.0;
        Give_doubleY = 0.0;
        Give_doubleZ = 0.0;
        
        
             TSx = new TimeSeries("", Millisecond.class);
              TSy = new TimeSeries("", Millisecond.class);
               TSz = new TimeSeries("", Millisecond.class);
             
             DataSetx =  new TimeSeriesCollection(TSx);
             DataSety =  new TimeSeriesCollection(TSy);
             DataSetz =  new TimeSeriesCollection(TSz);
            
             JFreeChart chartX = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("","", "",DataSetx ,true, true, false);
             JFreeChart chartY = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("","", "",DataSety ,true, true, false);
             JFreeChart chartZ = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("","", "",DataSetz ,true, true, false);
 //********************************************** X ***********************************************************************
                chartX.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( Color.BLACK );
                XYPlot plotX =  chartX.getXYPlot();     
                ValueAxis axisX = plotX.getDomainAxis();
        axisX.setAutoRange(true);
        axisX.setFixedAutoRange(50000.0); 
        axisX = plotX.getRangeAxis();
        axisX.setAutoRange(true);
                XYPlot xyPlotX = (XYPlot) chartX.getPlot();// LINE color
                XYItemRenderer rendererX = xyPlotX.getRenderer();// LINE color
                rendererX.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.GREEN);// LINE color
 //*******************************************************************************************************************   
 //********************************************** Y ***********************************************************************  
                chartY.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( Color.BLACK );
                XYPlot plotY =  chartY.getXYPlot();     
                ValueAxis axisY = plotY.getDomainAxis();
        axisY.setAutoRange(true);
        axisY.setFixedAutoRange(50000.0);
        axisY = plotY.getRangeAxis();
        axisY.setAutoRange(true);
                XYPlot xyPlotY = (XYPlot) chartY.getPlot();// LINE color
                XYItemRenderer rendererY = xyPlotY.getRenderer();// LINE color
                rendererY.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.magenta);// LINE color
 //*******************************************************************************************************************  
 //********************************************** Z *********************************************************************** 
                chartZ.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( Color.BLACK );
                XYPlot plotZ =  chartZ.getXYPlot();     
                ValueAxis axisZ = plotZ.getDomainAxis();
        axisZ.setAutoRange(true);
        axisZ.setFixedAutoRange(50000.0); 
        axisZ = plotZ.getRangeAxis();
        axisZ.setAutoRange(true);
                XYPlot xyPlotZ = (XYPlot) chartZ.getPlot();// LINE color
                XYItemRenderer rendererZ = xyPlotZ.getRenderer();// LINE color
                rendererZ.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.ORANGE);// LINE color
 
           ChartPanel chpax = new ChartPanel(chartX,700, 150, 100, 100, 1000, 300, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);//hatman bayad yek nemone az on sakhte beshe
           ChartPanel chpay = new ChartPanel(chartY,700, 150, 100, 100, 1000, 300, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);//hatman bayad yek nemone az on sakhte beshe
           ChartPanel chpaz = new ChartPanel(chartZ,700, 150, 100, 100, 1000, 300, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);//hatman bayad yek nemone az on sakhte beshe
           jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           jPanel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           jPanel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           jPanel1.add(chpax);
           jPanel2.add(chpay);
           jPanel3.add(chpaz);
           
       
    }

                         

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
      
        if(jToggleButton1.isSelected())
        {
            jToggleButton1.setText("DIS");
            
            ////////////////////////////////////////// Setup pipe //////////////////////////////////////////
try{
   //  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/linaro/hopo/output" ); we try by this But it did not matter
       
 
                  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
                  processBuilder.command("/home/linaro/hopo/output");
                  process =  processBuilder.start();
                  isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
                  BR = new BufferedReader(isr) ;
                 
}catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}  
            
                 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                 {
                   @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
    /////////////////////////////////////////////// WHILE ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            while(jToggleButton1.getText().equals("DIS")){
    ///////////////////////////////////////////// PIPE START /////////////////////////////////////////////
               
try {
             
              line = BR.readLine();
              System.out.println(line);
              
              Give_stringX = line.substring(0,12).toString().trim(); 
              Give_stringY = line.substring(14,26).toString().trim(); 
              Give_stringZ = line.substring(28,42).toString().trim(); 
            
                    Give_doubleX =   Double.parseDouble(Give_stringX);
                    Give_doubleY =   Double.parseDouble(Give_stringY);
                    Give_doubleZ =   Double.parseDouble(Give_stringZ);
                    
                    TSx.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(), Give_doubleX);
                    TSy.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(), Give_doubleY);
                    TSz.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(), Give_doubleZ);
                   
                } catch (Exception ex) { //SQLException
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
               
                }// END OF WHILE
            
        }
    });
    t.start();
            
        
        }else if(!jToggleButton1.isSelected())
        {
            try{
             process.destroy();
             process.destroyForcibly();
             isr.close();
             BR.close();
             jToggleButton1.setText("CO");
             System.out.println("goodbay");
             TSx.clear();
             TSy.clear();
             TSz.clear();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            
        }
     
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                     javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new DarculaLaf());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cha_time.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new cha_time().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're blocking the [*event dispatch thread*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Instead, try the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513) using [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25043676/230513), your implementation of `doInBackground()` can read asynchronously, publishing results as they arrive. In particular, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513), you can block `doInBackground()` while reading from your `ProcessBuilder`. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513), your implementation of `process()` can then safely update the chart's data model.

As an aside, consider the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) to tame the GUI editor.

Comment: Thanks for the very good help, the problem of delay has been solved, but now if we received 100 numbers per second, we will now receive 50 numbers and some of the data will disappear. Do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838349/230513), GUI update _rate_ is limited, but the background shouldn't miss data at 100 Hz. You'll probably have buffer on the background side, but you may be able to optimize the GUI side based on the `chunks` received by `process()`. See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513).