# Javafx music player not working

Tags: java, javafx

I'm coding a game in java, and I decided to add music to it. I tried with this code:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("music.mp3");
     MediaPlayer a = new MediaPlayer(new Media(resource.toString()));
     a.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
             a.seek(Duration.ZERO);
           }
       });
      a.play();
```

But for some reason, I get this error:

https://pastebin.com/UPkTbWHh

The file *music.mp3* is in the same folder as the class I'm running it from, and the code is running in the tick() method. Do anybody have an idea about how I can fix this?

Thanks, Lukas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2.1: Toolkit not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273773/javafx-2-1-toolkit-not-initialized)

Comment: Seems like you are trying to call this when the JavaFX toolkit is not running, somehow.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to fix that through...

Comment: Hey, please, post code / error from pastebin straightly into code block on this page, thanks

Comment: Ok, but I've passed that step now. And I will keep that in mind next time, but I think it would take too much place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to execute the above code from outside the context of a JavaFX app. `MediaPlayer` is a JavaFX component, so relies on the Toolkit being initialised, you can't (by default) just spin up a JFX component as you please.

The "proper" way is to subclass a JFX `Application` and then launch your application from there, which will initialise the JFX platform properly.

The "hack" way is to run the following line of code in the [Swing EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825281/java-swing-running-on-edt):

```
new JFXPanel();
```

...which will also have the side effect of initialising the JFX toolkit and allow you to create other JFX components.

As pointed out in the comments, since Java 9 you can use the less hacky method of:

```
Platform.startup(() -> {
    //Code to run on JFX thread
});
```

Comment: Note that there's another way to hack this, using [`Platform.startup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup-java.lang.Runnable-), though note that you can't call this method more than once, or if you have called `Application.launch()`, and you cannot call `Application.launch()` after calling it.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for that, didn't realise that had crept in since Java 9.

Comment: Now I'm going to sound like a jerk, but what is Swing EDT? :)

Comment: @Freeranger "EDT" = "Event Dispatch Thread". The thread on which Swing/AWT components are rendered and on which Swing/AWT events are processed.

Comment: I did that now, but now, I'm getting music, but it sounds VERY strange, it's the original music with some kind of weird additional sound that takes over completely

Comment: I fixed it! The mediaplayer start was in a loop :)